# Encoding images to video with ffmpeg

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ffmpeg

I am trying to encode series of images to one video file. I am using code from api-example.c, its works, but it gives me weird green colors in video. I know, I need to convert my RGB images to YUV, I found some solution, but its doesn't works, the colors is not green but very strange, so thats the code:

```
    // Register all formats and codecs
    av_register_all();

    AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int i, out_size, size, outbuf_size;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *picture;
    uint8_t *outbuf;

    printf("Video encoding\n");

    /* find the mpeg video encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO);
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "codec not found\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    c= avcodec_alloc_context();
    picture= avcodec_alloc_frame();

    /* put sample parameters */
    c->bit_rate = 400000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    c->width = 352;
    c->height = 288;
    /* frames per second */
    c->time_base= (AVRational){1,25};
    c->gop_size = 10; /* emit one intra frame every ten frames */
    c->max_b_frames=1;
    c->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open(c, codec) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* alloc image and output buffer */
    outbuf_size = 100000;
    outbuf = malloc(outbuf_size);
    size = c->width * c->height;

#pragma mark -
    AVFrame* outpic = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    int nbytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height);

    //create buffer for the output image
    uint8_t* outbuffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(nbytes);

#pragma mark -  
    for(i=1;i<77;i++) {
        fflush(stdout);

        int numBytes = avpicture_get_size(PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height);
        uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)av_malloc(numBytes*sizeof(uint8_t));

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"10%d", i]];
        CGImageRef newCgImage = [image CGImage];

        CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(newCgImage);
        CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(dataProvider);
        buffer = (uint8_t *)CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);   

        avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)picture, buffer, PIX_FMT_RGB8, c->width, c->height);
        avpicture_fill((AVPicture*)outpic, outbuffer, PIX_FMT_YUV420P, c->width, c->height);

        struct SwsContext* fooContext = sws_getContext(c->width, c->height, 
                                                PIX_FMT_RGB8, 
                                                c->width, c->height, 
                                                PIX_FMT_YUV420P, 
                                                SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        //perform the conversion
        sws_scale(fooContext, picture->data, picture->linesize, 0, c->height, outpic->data, outpic->linesize);
        // Here is where I try to convert to YUV

        /* encode the image */
        out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, outpic);
        printf("encoding frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, out_size);
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, out_size, f);

        free(buffer);
        buffer = NULL;      

    }

    /* get the delayed frames */
    for(; out_size; i++) {
        fflush(stdout);

        out_size = avcodec_encode_video(c, outbuf, outbuf_size, NULL);
        printf("write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", i, out_size);
        fwrite(outbuf, 1, outbuf_size, f);      
    }

    /* add sequence end code to have a real mpeg file */
    outbuf[0] = 0x00;
    outbuf[1] = 0x00;
    outbuf[2] = 0x01;
    outbuf[3] = 0xb7;
    fwrite(outbuf, 1, 4, f);
    fclose(f);
    free(outbuf);

    avcodec_close(c);
    av_free(c);
    av_free(picture);
    printf("\n");
```

Please give me advice how to fix that problem.

Comment: 1 question. What framework does the code above require?

Comment: It requires FFmpeg library http://www.ffmpeg.org/.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem... Could you please help me with your solution....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see article http://unick-soft.ru/Articles.cgi?id=20. But it is article on Russian, but it includes code samples and VS Example.

Answer (score 1):

Has anyone found a fix for this? I am seeing the green video problem on the decode side. That is, when I decode incoming PIX_FMT_YUV420 packets and then swsscale them to PIX_FMT_RGBA.

Thanks!

EDIT:
The green images are probably due to an arm optimization backfiring. I used this to fix the problem in my case:
http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/green-distorded-output-image-on-iPhone-td2231805.html

I guess the idea is to not specify any architecture (the config will you a warning about the architecture being unknown but you can continue to 'make' anyway). That way, the arm optimizations are not used. There maybe a slight performance hit (if any), but atleast it works! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is most likely that you are using `PIX_FMT_RGB8` as your input pixel format.  This does not mean 8 bits per channel like the commonly used 24-bit RGB or 32-bit ARGB.  It means 8 bits per pixel, meaning that all three color channels are housed in a single byte.  I am guessing that this is not the format of your image since it is quite uncommon, so you need to use `PIX_FMT_RGB24` or `PIX_FMT_RGB32` depending on whether or not your input image has an alpha channel.  See [this documentation](http://cekirdek.pardus.org.tr/~ismail/ffmpeg-docs/ffmpeg-r_2libavutil_2avutil_8h.html) page for info on the pixel formats.

Comment: Thanks. I tried PIX_FMT_RGB24 and PIX_FMT_RGB32 and many others. I used PIX_FMT_RGB8 because my images was optimized for network, its indexed 8bit colors pngs and other photoshop stuff to make it smaller. But I tried other images in usual formats, just to check, with different options of PIX_FMT, it still gives me wrong result, so I think the trouble in code.

Comment: Did you try PIX_FMT_PAL8?  That format is for 8-bit indexed color.  With PIX_FMT_PAL8, a color palette must be sent along with the frame.  That documentation page I linked to talks about it right before defining all of the pixel formats. It says that AVFrame.data[0] contains indexes into the palette for each pixel while AVFrame.data[1] contains a 1024 byte array defining the actual ARGB color values for each 8-bit index.