# Live streaming on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, streaming

I just started work on live streaming on iPhone. So any help of how to do live streming in iPhone. I think if I can add video tag in HTML5 and then load that html in UIWebView will work.
Am I right? If not what is your sugestion to do live streaming. I want to embed some news channel live streaming link in the application so from where I can find those links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to go through HTTP Live streaming document provided by Apple.There are some sample live streaming URLs.The file extension will be .m3u8.If you want to configure your own webwserver , you have to configure FFMPEG server in your webserver.The links which will help you 
1)[Apple document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/iPhoneStreamingMediaOverview/iPhoneStreamingMediaOverview.html)
2)[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093667/http-live-streaming-ffmpeg-ffserver-and-iphone-os-3)
3)[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334939/encoding-images-to-video-with-ffmpeg)
4)[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248316/video-generation-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: what i want to do is to stream news channel like bbc news or others in my application. now what u suggest i should only use http live streaming or MPMoviePlayerController is enough.

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController is enough if you use the .m3u8 URL....search .m3u8 free urls whether it broadcasts news channel or not.otherwise you have to implement ffmpeg through your own effort in maitaining your server...please mark answer if you are satisfied..

Comment: apple document link has expired ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're making a web app in html5 then the video tag is a good choice.

But, If you're developing a native app then MPMoviePlayerController would be a much better choice. There are many example of how to use it online.

iOS doesn't support RTMP or RSTP, so your stream would need to be a HTTP Live stream.  From memory the codec choice is very limited too, eg if you supply H264+mp3 you won't get any sound despite iOS supporting mp3.

Also remember that streams from other people (such as the BBC) will normally be protected by international copyright law, so unless you have prior permission to use their stream in your app you may be breaking the law.

Comment: does mpmoviePlayerController support live streaming. and from where i can take those live streaming links from different news channel like bbc.

Comment: Yes. But the source needs to support http live streaming too. If you're a paid dev you'll have access to the wwdc2010 videos. There was a great session on HTTP Live streaming.

Comment: No worries, i've updated my answer with some more information and advice.

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/institutional/2009/03/000000_mobile.shtml check that link. i just used that link provided in that link to play in iphone but it does not show any thing. any help

Answer (score 0):

Apple has some nice resources on [Http Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/).

Comment: i just check http live streaming but it looks me too difficult. can u provide me good exmaple link of this.